# SQL: I need to select the rows with max column for each group of data in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a join result table like this (with more columns):

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| salesid    | itemid    | confirmid | confirmdocnum | createddatetime |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| a0001      | foo       |        21 |      2501-1   |   2019-01-02    |
| a0001      | bar       |        21 |      2501-1   |   2019-01-02    |
| a0001      | baz       |        22 |      2501-2   |   2019-01-03    |
| a0001      | foo       |        23 |      2501-3   |   2019-01-04    |
| a0001      | bar       |        23 |      2501-3   |   2019-01-04    |
| a0002      | foo       |        24 |      2502-1   |   2019-01-01    |
| a0002      | bar       |        24 |      2502-1   |   2019-01-01    |
| a0002      | bar       |        25 |      2502-2   |   2019-01-03    |
| a0003      | foo       |        26 |      2503-1   |   2019-01-04    |
| a0003      | bar       |        27 |      2503-2   |   2019-01-07    |
| a0004      | baz       |        28 |      2504-1   |   2019-01-05    |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I need to retrieve something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| salesid    | itemid    | confirmid | confirmdocnum | createddatetime |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
| a0001      | foo       |        23 |      2501-3   |   2019-01-04    |
| a0001      | bar       |        23 |      2501-3   |   2019-01-04    |
| a0002      | bar       |        25 |      2502-2   |   2019-01-03    |
| a0003      | bar       |        27 |      2503-2   |   2019-01-07    |
| a0004      | baz       |        28 |      2504-1   |   2019-01-05    |
+------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I need for each salesid all the rows with the latest confirmdocnum. The latest confirmdocnum can be like '%-1', '%-2', '%-3', ..., '%-n'

All the rows with the latest confirmdocnum has always the latest createddatetime.

The join I use to get the first table is:

```
SELECT cct.salesid, 
       cct.itemid, 
       ccj.confirmid, 
       ccj.confirmdocnum, 
       ccj.createddatetime
FROM AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmjour AS ccj
LEFT JOIN AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmtrans AS cct
ON cct.salesid=ccj.salesid
  AND cct.confirmid=ccj.confirmid
  AND cct.confirmdate=ccj.confirmdate
WHERE ccj.CREATEDDATETIME >= CONVERT (DATE,'2019/01/01')
```

But I can't figure how to pick only the lines I need. There are several extra columns that I simplified. This extra columns have the data I really need. I tried a `GROUP BY` aproximation, but can't take the data of the rows I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY salesid,itemid` take the `MAX(confirmdocnum)` and `JOIN` with your result to get the row you want.I could not test it but something like this should work:

```
    SELECT t1.* 
    FROM (
    SELECT cct.salesid, 
           cct.itemid, 
           ccj.confirmid, 
           ccj.confirmdocnum, 
           ccj.createddatetime
    FROM AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmjour AS ccj
    LEFT JOIN AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmtrans AS cct
    ON cct.salesid=ccj.salesid
      AND cct.confirmid=ccj.confirmid
      AND cct.confirmdate=ccj.confirmdate
    WHERE ccj.CREATEDDATETIME >= CONVERT (DATE,'2019/01/01')
    ) t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT cct.salesid,cct.itemid,MAX(ccj.confirmdocnum) AS max_confirmdocnum
    FROM AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmjour AS ccj
    LEFT JOIN AxDynamics.dbo.custconfirmtrans AS cct
    ON cct.salesid=ccj.salesid
      AND cct.confirmid=ccj.confirmid
      AND cct.confirmdate=ccj.confirmdate
    WHERE ccj.CREATEDDATETIME >= CONVERT (DATE,'2019/01/01')
    GROUP BY cct.salesid,cct.itemid
    ) t2 
ON t1.salesid=t2.salesid AND t1.itemid=t2.itemid AND t1.confirmdocnum=t2.max_confirmdocnum
```